# Candidate Boolean Function with efficient rational representation compared to polynomial representation

Tags: boolean-functions

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots x_n$ be literals.

Let $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be a boolean function.

Let $d$ be the smallest degree of $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb R[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ that represents $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ (where represents means $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ agree on $x_i\in\{0,1\}$).

Is there a candidate boolean function $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ such that the smallest degree of $r(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in \mathbb R(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ (sum of degrees of numerator and denominator) that represents $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ (where represents means $R(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ agree on $x_i\in\{0,1\}$) is $d^a$ for some $a\in(0,1)$?

Note that $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ and the numerator and denominator of $r(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ can be multilinear since $x_i^t=x_i$ on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: What was the answer to Emil's question given in the comments to your [previous question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27051/representing-boolean-function-by-a-rational-function)

Comment: I have made a new comment there.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Is there a positive answer for the question here?

Comment: I am not aware of any, but I haven't really worked with rational representation.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Thank you for the answer. Atleast would you know of a paper or a reference that covers this topic?

Comment: I am not aware of any references that cover the question, and actually as far as I know it is still an open problem to prove a significant separation. As I recall, Lance Fortnow considered the problem once, motivated by some oracle separations.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen Thank you very much. Do you know which paper by Fortnow?

Comment: There is no paper!

Comment: thank you very much again but atleast do you know the separations he considered to work on? That could be a better than nothing or so lead on the topic.

Comment: ... and I told you all I know.

Comment: @KristofferArnsfeltHansen The paper by nisan states a structural complexity implication if we can consider rational representations. But it does not say what implications?